# How to implement left associativity if there is a method (instead of a variable) after the operator sign?

Tags: java, algorithm, associativity

Lately I've been getting back to coding (haven't done it in a while). I am trying to write a program which will save and perform operations on sets in left associative order instead of right associative order.

```
SetInterface<BigInteger> performOperation(Scanner in, SetInterface<BigIneger> firstSet) {
      SetInterface<BigInteger> result = new Set<BigInteger>();

      SetInterface<BigInteger> secondSet = nextSet(in); //this line will read the next set, and will call performOperation()

      if (operator == '+') {
            result = ((Set<BigInteger>) firstSet).union((Set) secondSet);
            //I have tried the below two lines of code, but they both did not result in left associtivity
            //result = secondSet.union((Set) firstSet);
            //result = result.union((Set) secondSet);
      }

      return result;
```

My union method in my Set class looks like this:

```
public Set union(Set secondSet) {
        Set<T> result = new Set<T>();
        Set<T> secondSetCopy = new Set<T>();

        result.set = (LinkedList<T>) this.set.copy();
        secondSetCopy.set = (LinkedList<T>) secondSet.set.copy();

        while (secondSetCopy.size() > 0) {
            result.add((T) secondSetCopy.get());
            secondSetCopy.remove(secondSetCopy.get());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The above code results in something like this: A + (B + (C + D)) 
What I would like to achieve is this: ((A + B) + C) + D

I would really appreciate it if anyone has any tips on how I can tackle this problem.